# class missing after Importing spring framework project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven

I am new to spring framework and having basic knowledge of maven. I tried to import spring project in eclipse. (File - Import - Existing Maven Projects). I see that,

1) The project is not imported as java project. i.e. if I right click on project and see the properties, I dont see options such as Java build path, Java Compiler etc.

2) I am looking for one particular class in the project, but it is not there, although I can see that class from terminal. Therefore it very much exists in the project. So why cant I see it in Eclipse ? Why is it not imported with the project ?

Please note that I use Eclipse_Juno and I can compile the project with maven on terminal and in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that could have gone wrong. Hard to say what happened.

If the project you have imported builds on the command line (`mvn clean install`) then chances are good it is importable into an IDE with not much trouble once the settings are ok.

Make sure you have the m2e (maven 2 eclipse) plugin available. So eclipse can detect its a maven project. If you also use spring I would give the Spring Tool Suite (STS) a try: http://spring.io/tools

If the project is not recognized as java - or the essential facets are not detected - I would try to figure out why. Maybe something in the preferences is not properly set up? (maven home, executables, sdk, ...)